# Prove that $\text{ord}_{2^n}(x) = 2^k$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime. Define $v_p(x)$ such that if $v_p(x) = n$, then $p^n \mid x$ but $p^{n+1} \nmid x$. Prove that if $v_2(x^{2^k}-1) = n$ where $\gcd(x,2^n) = 1$, then $\text{ord}_{2^n}(x) = 2^k$.

I discovered this result while solving a question with $x = 3$.

We see that if $n \geq 2$ is an integer and $r$ is even, if $v_2(3^r-1) = n$, then $v_2(3^{2r}-1) = n+1$. Otherwise if $n$ is odd then if $v_2(3^r-1) = n$, then $v_2(3^{2r}-1) = n+2$. Thus listing $$v_2(3-1) = 1, v_2(3^2-1) = 3,v_2(3^4-1) = 4, v_2(3^8-1) = 5$$ and the result is easily verified from this.

Can this be generalized to any prime $p$ and not just $2$?

Comment: How is $\text{ord}_{2^n}(x)$ defined?

Comment: @Lubin It is the multiplicative order.

Comment: Sorry, I need a more complete definition. You seem to have a function $\text{ord}_y(x)$, and I don’t know how the two variables work together to give an integer value.

Comment: You must look at the lemma which is called "lifting lhe exponent lemma". That tells us all information we need.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get everything you need from the fact that if $m\equiv1\pmod4$, then $v_2(m^2-1)=1+v_2(m-1)$. This is easily verified by expanding $m^2=\bigl[1+(m-1)\bigr]^2$ as $1+2(m-1)+(m-1)^2$. What this is saying is that if $m$ is $2$-adically close to $1$, then squaring it gets it closer to $1$, but not a great deal closer.

In case $m\equiv3\pmod4$, then use the above on $-m\equiv1\pmod4$.

The story is much simpler for $p>2$. In that case, if $m\equiv1\pmod p$, then $v_p(m^p-1)=1+v_p(m-1)$, with no special cases.